# Adding extra fields to Django site

Tags: django

I have a project that uses Django's `django.contrib.sites.models.Site` framework, Now I need to store an additional value per site.

Currently, site contains the below fields

```
 id     | integer                | not null 
 domain | character varying(100) | not null                                                 | extended |              |
 name   | character varying(50)  | not null
```

And here is the model

```
class Site(models.Model):    
    domain = models.CharField( _('domain name'), max_length=100, validators=[_simple_domain_name_validator], unique=True, )
    name = models.CharField(_('display name'), max_length=50)
```

What is the cleaner way of adding an extra field to the `Site` with a minimal footprint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you extend the Site model in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2821702/how-do-you-extend-the-site-model-in-django)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you can simply create a subclass of `Site` and add your extra field there:

```
class CustomSite(Site):
     custom_field = models.CharField(max_length=150)
```

After that, make sure to make and run migrations:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Hope it helps!